# set textview to other xml in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I am doing an android project which uses a Tabhost to link to 3 fragments and need some communication between them. Each tab will include another xml file. I linked different element in different sml file to the `.java` file. But it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

In Main.xml

```
<TabHost>
 <LinearLayout>
  <include 
 android:id="@+id/fragmentreview" 
 layout="@layout/fragentreview"/>
 </LinearLayout>`
```

In fragentreview.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewinfragR"
   android:text="Text in new xml reviews" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

In fragment.class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragentreview, container, false);
    txtMsgR = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewinfragR);
    txtMsgR.setText("Main Car integer = ");
    return rootView;
}
```

When I launch the app **textViewinfragR** it should show `Main Car integer =` but it is still showing `Text in new xml reviews`. Is there a problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the text in the wrong place. Try setting it in onActivityCreated

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    txtMsgR = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewinfragR);
    txtMsgR.setText("Main Car integer = ");
}
```

This should work. The onViewCreated method is called after the inflation is completed.

onCreateView -> onViewCreated -> onActivityCreated

Comment: Hi I edited my answer slightly. Use the view object given to you for onViewCreated

Comment: Also please ensure that you're using TabHost correctly. [link] (http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-tabwidget-example.html) Here is an example of TabHost using activities but using fragments is fine.